Computing a limit using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.
I would like to resolve a paradox I'm arriving at when I want to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits to actually compute limits. I learned a theorem in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis that says for $a, b, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, $a < b+\epsilon$ then $a\leq b$.
With the assumption that a limit exists for say $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}; x\mapsto \{(x+1)(x-1)\}/(x-1)$ at $x_0=1$, I want to use this theorem to compute the limit, if it has one, using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.
We have from the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition that if a limit exists for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ for which $0<|x-1|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)|<\epsilon$. Assuming this is the case, taking both positive and negative values of the argument of the modulus and applying the theorem, I eventually find that both $f(x)\leq\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)\leq f(x)$ must both be true if the limit exists, which only happens in the case of equality otherwise we have a contradiction. And so the problem comes when comparing the sides of this equality. For $0<|x-1|<\delta$, $f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f(x)$ and substituting the function's definition for $0<|x-1|<\delta \Leftrightarrow x \neq 1 $ and $1-\delta<x<1+\delta$, $$\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}}.$$
If the limit exists, I think the R.H.S. is a constant, but then the L.H.S. is not constant as it is only defined for $\delta>0$. However, if you substitute the endpoints of the interval $1 \pm \delta$ in the expression on the left, you find
$$\frac{(1 \pm \delta+1)(1 \pm \delta-1)}{1 \pm \delta-1},$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 \pm \delta+1,$$
$$\Rightarrow 2 \pm \delta.$$
Comparing the L.H.S. to the R.H.S. again, we see that it is only constant if $\delta=0$, which computes the limit, though if we supposed $\delta=0$ then we could not perform, then the previous assumption, namely that $$\frac{(1 \pm \delta-1)}{1 \pm \delta-1}=1.$$
I know that the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit does not require the point at $x=1 $ to be even defined, so why do the criteria for a limit's existence seem to require in some way $\delta>0$ and $\delta=0$ and in a broader sense that a function's limit is a removable one; for which one can see how the function is just undefined at a point in the contrived manner I just did so multiplying the function $x+1$ by $(x-1)/(x-1)$.
Somewhat related to this, I was wondering if you could define limits as being not unique but two numbers that in this example would be $2\pm \delta \text{ really small}$, as this seems to also resolve the paradox.

Perhaps an extension to the question, that I'll put as another question if that is better, is if I used the hyperreals for a moment to do a proof by contradiction. I am also going to alter the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition slightly to allow $\delta$ be a positive hyperreal, which I don't think will change much as it is a superset, but someone can correct if I am being naïve. So my goal is to try correctly apply Apostol's Theorem.
I'm going to assume the function $f(x)$ has $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$. This means it satisfies the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, which means for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can always find some $\delta>0$ for which $0<|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)|<\epsilon.$
Assuming this is the case in the hopes of finding conditions on the limit, I will use the definition of an infinitesimal I found on wikipedia. An infinitesimal is a hyperreal number $\lambda$ for which for every integer $n$, $|\lambda|<1/n$.
For a positive infinitesimal $\delta_0$, I will let $\delta=\delta_0$. This should still satisfy the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition but $\delta_0$ should be a sufficient $\delta>0$, for every $\epsilon>0$ (which supersedes the for some $\delta>0$ condition,) as it is in some sense, I think, the infimum of the values $\delta>0$.
$x_0-\delta_0 \leq x \leq x_0 + \delta_0\text{ and }x \neq 0 \Rightarrow x \in \{x_0 \pm \delta_0\}$. So for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta=\delta_0>0$ for which $|f(x)-\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)|<\epsilon$. I can just take both cases of $x \in \{x_0 \pm \delta_0\}$. $|f(x_0 \pm \delta_0)-\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)|<\epsilon$. First taking positive $\delta_0$ and the positive argument of the modulus, I find for my above example that for every $\epsilon>0$
$$\frac{(1+\delta_0+1)(1+\delta_0-1)}{1+\delta_0-1} \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}}+\epsilon.$$
$$\Rightarrow 2+\delta_0 \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}}.$$
Similarly it can be shown that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}} \leq 2+\delta_0.$$
And similar can be shown for negative $\delta_0$. We then find for the limit to exist
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1}{\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}}=2 \pm \delta_0.$$
This shows that $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) \in\text{*}\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ but the $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x) \in\mathbb{R}$ a contradiction. Also you would find a contradiction anyway allowing hyperreal solutions as the limit would be a unique pair not a unique value.
I don't really know if I've used the infinitesimal stuff correctly but I hope the argument is at the very least valid though changing the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition slightly may have undermined the entire thing.

It looks like you set $a=f(x)$ and $b=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x),.$ Now comes the problem. The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit does not tell you that $a<b+\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon,.$ What must your $x$ in $a$ satisfy? Where did your $\delta$ go?

If $a\not\le b$, then $a\gt b$ and $a=b+(a-b)$. Since $a-b\gt 0$, this contradicts the fact that $a\lt b+\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon\gt 0$.

@KurtG. The $x$ in $a$ must satisfy $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$. If this is the case then for every $\epsilon >0, a < b+\epsilon$.

No. The $\delta$ (hence all the $x$ for which the inequality $a(x)<b+\epsilon$ holds) depends on $\epsilon,.$ If it didn't you would wrongly deduce the paradox that $f(x)=b$ for every $x,.$ (Or at least for every $x$ in an open neighbourhood.) This is far more than $f(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x),.$

Sorry yes. So then if for every $\epsilon>0$ you can find $\delta>0$ for which for $x$ depending on $\delta$ which depends on $\epsilon$, $f(x)=b$ why does the equality not hold for every $\epsilon$ assuming there is some $\delta$ every time.

Can you explain the connection to the nonstandard-analysis tag?

@BrianTung Well I only learnt about nonstandard-analysis today but I thought maybe someone who has studied that might have some insight to give. $\delta>0$ and $\delta=0$ at different points which seems connected to the hyper-reals and infinitesimals, though I wouldn't know as I have not studied those yet.

I would remove that tag, if the question does not intrinsically deal with non-standard analysis. It's going to be confusing for site users, I think.

How does that square with say $f(x)=-x^2 \leq 2.$ Why would that make sense even though the LHS is a function and the RHS a constant?

Now looking at this, I think I'm showing that the limit would not exist if we were restricted to a function $f(x)$ which doesn't define the point at $x=1$ and we must look for a similar function that does define the point at $x=1$. This means that just because the limit definition is independent of a point being defined its independency may still be changed to a dependency to compute the limit even if that computation wouldn't rely on the same definition. This is because the case $f(x_0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)$ is just as true under the definition of the limit…

…The limit definition does not care about if the function at $x=x_0$ is defined. This gives us two cases to consider: the case where it is not defined and the case where it is defined. Before in my calculations I was assuming that the limit definition forced the function to not be defined at a point when it doesn’t force that at all.

@YvesDaoust if the inequality does not hold then I think that shows that the specific function I mentioned can't define the limit. So it's just an untrue statement.


"if I used the hyperreals for a moment to do a proof by contradiction"

If you use the hyperreals, then you don't need to do a proof by contradiction, but can instead give a direct argument.  The limit $$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}$$
is by definition the standard part of $\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{x-1}$ when $x=1+\alpha$ for a nonzero infinitesimal $\alpha$. After canceling $\alpha$ in the numerator and denominator, we immediately get st$(1+\alpha+1)=2$.

This definition of the limit is a lot more intuitive but it also seems to capture the why of how you actually compute the limit in being so direct. Though I'm sure it is important to know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, I'm glad to know this tool as well as it helps me understand the other. Is there any resource you could point me to that links both definitions as equivalent? thanks

This is proved in section 6.6 of https://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/coursenotes.pdf

Let me offer a logical critique of the material in your post.
The statement you wish to apply, taken from Apostol's book, has a certain logical structure which you are ignoring. This leads to logical mistakes in applying that statement. Here is the full statement with all of the logical quantifiers and logical connectives in the correct position:

For all $a \in \mathbb R$ and for all $b \in \mathbb R$, $\biggl($if  (for all $\epsilon > 0$, $a \le b+\epsilon$) then ($a \le b$) $\biggr)$.

You can see from the structure of this statement that the three universal quantifiers are occuring in different contexts. You are instead ignoring that structure and treating the three universal quantifiers on $a$, $b$ and $\epsilon$ in the same manner.
The proper way to apply this theorem from Apostol's book is to use the method for applying any "for all" statement that is known to be true: you take any two fixed values for $a$ and $b$; you may then conclude that the statement-in-parentheses is true; and you then apply that statement-in-parentheses using those two fixed values. That statement in parentheses is an if-then statement, and to apply that it you use the method for applying any "if-then" statement that is know to be true: you must first prove that the for-all statement "for all $\epsilon > 0$, $a \le b+\epsilon$" is true, and you may finally conclude that $a \le b$ (using your fixed values of $a$ and $b$).
To summarize: because you are applying Apostol's theorem, the universal quantifiers on $a$ and $b$ tell you that you can proceed only after fixing $a$ and $b$; then, because you are applying the if-then statement in parentheses, you must prove its hypothesis "for all $\epsilon > 0$, $a \le b+\epsilon$"; and then because you are proving that hypothesis, you may assume that $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary and you must then prove that $a \le b+\epsilon$ (and keep in mind at this point that $a$ and $b$ have previously been fixed).
Note well: Applying a universal quantified statement and proving a universal quantified statement are two very different logical operations.
What you are doing instead is to take the variable value $a = f(x)$, and the perhaps-nonexistent-value $b = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$, and the variable value $\epsilon$, and you are mooshing them all together, treating their universal quantifiers logically in the exact same way.
That leads to an invalid argument.

What I suggest is that you learn carefully how to distinguish several logical operations:

How to prove an if-then statement, versus how to apply an if-then statement.


How to prove a for all statement, versus how to apply a for all statement.

And, while you're at it, you might as well learn:

How to prove an existence statement, versus how to apply an existence statement.


Also, try to avoid going on long logical excursions using perhaps-nonexistent-values; that's a good thing for building your intuition about a problem to try to understand the problem; but it's very bad for writing a proof.
What one does instead for this problem is to use one's mathematical experience to guess the appropriate limit value; in this case one guesses $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 2$. Then one proves that the definition of the limit holds using that value.

I think I am understanding. So if I take some fixed value of $x$ within the interval, I have to show that it is true for every $\epsilon>0$ but I don't show that for a specific $x$ value within the interval which depends on a specific $\epsilon>0$. Every $\epsilon>0$ in each case only pauses on a specific range of values where the specific inequality for the function isn't proven for every $\epsilon>0$. My fixed value depends on $\epsilon$ but I also have to show that that value should be true for all $\epsilon>0$ for which the fixed value of $x$ in the interval might change.

I realise I might have made an error in precedence when I state the theorem in my question, where would you state that $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$. Would it something like $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}\text{ and }\epsilon>0$ because the way I put it seems to put $a, b\text{ and }\epsilon$ on the same level when I only meant to specify the domain which should be implicit anyway but I messed things up whatever way I've done it.

Very nice answer that deals with the underlying confusion over dealing with quantifiers, and proving vs. using. If there were Hot Network Answers, I'd nominate this one.

@JonathanZ and you could also nominate my question for Hot Network Blunders while you're at it!

Nah, everyone goofs up from time to time. Ain't no worry.

I believe that the contradiction found proves that the limit can't be computed using $f(x)$, where the point of the limit $x_0$ isn't defined.
This is because the limit definition does not care whether a function $f(x)$ is defined at the point $x_0$ of which you are seeking to get the limit. And so there are two cases to consider $f(x)$ not defined at the point of the limit $x_0$ and $g(x)=f(x)$ defined everywhere including $x_0$. And there are infinitely many $g(x)$ because $g(x_0)$ may be defined as any value. Though the limit if it exists will find the unique one that works with the definition and is close to the function $f(x)$ about the point $x_0$. The condition that $g(x)$ only differ from $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is important as the limit in the definition does not care about the function at the specific point $x_0$ but for the limit of $f(x)$ it does care about its points elsewhere, for it to be the limit of '$f(x)$'. And so for it to remain the limit of $f(x)$, $g(x)$ must be the same elsewhere.
The first case is always going to be redundant I think by my contradiction found which shows $\delta=0$ and $\delta>0$. This means we must only consider the second case which might seem like a trivial result but helps me understand why we are allowed to look for other similar functions.
